# How to obtain an array of hexadecimal codes from an image?

Tags: php, hex, bmp

I need to convert a .bmp image to a hex array in PHP.

I have tried to create a function for this but it has not worked

```php
function bmp_to_hex($filename) {   
    $bmp = file_get_contents($filename);   
    $output = '';   
    for($i=0; $i < strlen($bmp); $i++) {     
        $output .= dechex(ord($test{$i}));   
    }   
    return $output; 
}
```

Is there a function in PHP for this? If not, how should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done any research? What were your findings?

Comment: I have also looked for information about the php bin2hex function but I think it is not what I need

Comment: Are you trying to build a hex viewer for the BMP format? How have you determined that the output was incorrect? Please provide a test sample of a few bytes and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ready-made function for it. You can do the following:

```
function bmp_to_hex($filename) {   
  $bmpStr = file_get_contents($filename);   
  $hexStr = bin2hex($bmpStr);
  $hexArray = str_split($hexStr,2);
  return $hexArray;
}
```

The $bmpStr ist a string like "BMF>(..".
$hexStr is a string like "424d460000 .." with the 2-character values.
An array is then created with str_split. The array then starts like this:  {[0] => string (2) "42" [1] => string (2) "4d".

Note: Bitmaps can get very large. $hexStr becomes twice as large. The array of these then requires a very huge amount of memory.